# How to show new line from text area mvc4?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I use mvc4 and i use arabic languge in the view(lang="ar") ,the flowing code store text in sql table
for example :مرحبامرحبا
is stored in sql table but when it is readed from sql table  the output
:

```
 مرحبا <\br> مرحبا
```

I want the output to be like this:

مرحبا

مرحبا

```
modelcar.CarDescription = modelcar.CarDescription
                         .Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
AdvertFunObj.Add(modelcar);
```

the view

```
<br />
<hr /><br />
الاضافات<span class="blue"><%:Model.CarDescription   %></span><br />
```

Comment: he did ask the question in English...

Comment: Try '\r\n' in place of <br>

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `Html.Raw` to output HTML in your view, otherwise it's just treated as a string. Try this:

```
الاضافات<span class="blue"><%:Html.Raw(Model.CarDescription)   %></span><br />
```

**Edit:** Although as commenters have said, make sure you haven't turned off `RequestValidation` otherwise it'd be vulnerable to XSS attacks (that's if you actually are allowing people to be adding cars).

Comment: Wouldn't this open the door for XSS? if someone manage to store a script in CarDescription it could be executed on client side

Comment: @LuisTellez He should be validating his data **before** it hits the database anyway (that's if he actually allows people to add cars in his system)

Comment: If he has turned off the ASP.NET setting RequestValidation and he isn't sanitizing the input before storage the yeah. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339.aspx

Comment: @coding-ninja Which he **should** be using anyway :)

Comment: Yeah :)  I don't dare to turn it off on a public facing site.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using the razor view engine, the way to not encode the HTML would be to write:

```
<hr /><br />
الاضافات<span class="blue">@Html.Raw(Model.CarDescription)</span><br />
```

Maybe try

```
<hr /><br />
الاضافات<span class="blue"><%: Html.Raw(Model.CarDescription %></span><br />
```